# jailbreak gone bad - how to fix? (running ios 7.0.3 and used evasion)

Tags: jailbreak

I've tried jailbreaking my 4S running 7.0.3 using evasi0n, but this resulted in a bootloop (i.e. stuck at apple logo) which seems to be quite common! :/

Anyway, I've searched the net for solutions and it seems the only way to get this fix is to restore using IPSW.

But since I'm running on iOS7, I wanna keep it that way.

Is there a way to restore my phone running iOS 7.0.3 to the same version? I've always seen replies where people says they can't downgrade to an earlier version because Apple has stopped signing. So I'm not really sure how this works when it comes to staying on the same but old version.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You would have to restore via a jailbreak tool. But I'm not very informed on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple doesn't sign iOS 7 for the iPhone 4s any more which means that you can't install it, regardless of what your current version of iOS is.

However, you may be able to do a semi-restore using [semirestore7](http://semirestore7.info).